# Heroku: This is the legacy CLI error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Every time I enter 
    heroic update
I get this following message

```
This is the legacy Heroku CLI. Please install the new CLI from https://cli.heroku.com
heroku-cli: Updating CLI... already on latest version: 6.12.0-a504409
heroku-cli: Updating plugins... done
 !    `heroku update` is only available from Heroku Toolbelt.
 !    Download and install from https://toolbelt.heroku.com
```

but I did click on the link and reinstalled it, and when I try again, the same message pops up. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding HEROKU_DEBUG=1 to the command , it will tell any trouble it have have.

You can also try with DEBUG=* to see more verbose output of command.

Error logs files are stored at

`MacOS  ~/Library/Caches/heroku/error.log
Windows %LOCALAPPDATA%\heroku\error.log
Linux/Other ~/.cache/heroku/error.log (or XDG_CACHE_HOME if set)`

reference https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#troubleshooting